# how to change memory guarded by std::shared_ptr(unique_ptr)

Tags: c++, memory

I want to use unique and shared_ptr to take care of allocated memory. But as far as I can see the access to the memory(get,...) is always const and return const pointer so I cannot manipulate the memory stored.

EXAMPLE:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr( new int[42]);

memset(ptr.get(),0,42*sizeof(int)); //not possible ptr.get() returns const pointer
```

Is there a work around? If there is no way to manipulate the memory, what are the design reasons to not offer such an interface?

Comment: Why do you want to use `memset`? And why use a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` instead of a `std::vector`?

Comment: you cannot steal memory (take ownership like release) from std::vector

Comment: @user1235183 it is a `const pointer`, not a `pointer to const` you can change the contents it points to without any issues. But you might need some casts if you want to use c functions like memset.

Comment: this answers my question

Comment: I was wrong actually, the pointer it returns isn't even const, the function itself is const

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, "stealing memory" is either a code smell, or an attempt to work around a deficient `C` library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function signature for `std::unique_ptr::get` is

[`pointer get() const;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get)

the type of `pointer` being "`std::remove_reference<Deleter>::type::pointer` if that type exists, otherwise `T*`"

The only `const` in that signature being for the function itself, so that it can be called on a `const std::unique_ptr<int> a;`

So your premise of `and return const pointer` is not true. You can change the memory pointed to by a smart pointer via a pointer retrieved from its `get()` member function.

Additionally `memset(ptr.get(),0,42*sizeof(int));` is also fine and doesn't need any casts because you can still implicitly convert any pointer to a void pointer according to [this pointer-conversion rule](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion):

`A prvalue pointer to any (optionally cv-qualified) object type T can be converted to a prvalue pointer to (identically cv-qualified) void. The resulting pointer represents the same location in memory as the original pointer value. If the original pointer is a null pointer value, the result is a null pointer value of the destination type.`

So, your code has no issues and seems to be compliant with the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Now that the mechanics of `std::unique_ptr<>::get()` are understood, you may see some value in a more idiomatic algorithm-based approach.

Arguably it's more readable, avoids casts, will work should you change your mind about the underlying storage and is just as efficient.

some examples:

```
std::fill(ptr.get(), ptr.get() + 42, 0);

std::fill(&ptr[0], &ptr[42], 0);

std::fill(std::addressof(ptr[0]), std::addressof(ptr[42]), 0);
```

and with a little boilerplate:

```
for (auto& x : linear_range(ptr.get(), 42)) {
  x = 0;
}
```

With optimisations enabled, all of these evaluate to the same efficient code.

boilerplate is here:

```
template<class I1, class I2>
struct range_impl {

  auto begin() const { return i1; }
  auto end() const { return i2; }
  I1 i1;
  I2 i2;
};

template<class I1, class I2>
auto range(I1 i1, I2 i2) {
  return range_impl<I1, I2> { i1, i2 };
}

template<class I1>
auto linear_range(I1 i1, std::size_t length) {
  return range(i1, std::next(i1, length));
}
```